# Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1 does not offer Bulgarian phonetic keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1 on a laptop. However, the keyboard layout settings offer just Bulgarian, and when selected it turns out to be the traditional layout, which is really confusing if your keyboard does not have the Cyrillic characters on its keys. Besides music production, I would also like to use the laptop for my everyday browsing needs, and I happen to need Bulgarian phonetic. Could someone please help with ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My plain vanilla Ubuntu system contains a keyboard version of Bulgarian phonetic.  I've posted it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10087374/).

Download this file to `~/downloads/bg.txt` and compare it to your current keyboard lay-out file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bg` by using the following command:

```
diff ~/downloads/bg.txt /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bg
```

If they are identical (which they should be) just go to the dash by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, type `system settings`, click the only remaining icon and add a new keyboard and take Bulgarian phonetic from the list and you're up and running!

If they are not identical, copy the file over yours by the following command:

```
sudo cp ~/downloads/bg.txt /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bg
```

and then take the solution for identical keyboards.

щастлива типизиране!